# Can I use vue.js to keep track of changes in d3.js scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js. I would like to have a Vue.js instance bind an svg element attribute to a d3.js scale. I want to do it in a way so that when I later on change the scale range or domain (e.g. in another context the max domain value needs to be higher) the old element will also adapt. This would be useful if for example two visualizations share the same colour legend and I therefore want to use the same scale.

```
<div id="example">
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" :fill="color"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
<script>
  let colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().range(['#FFFFFF', '#0000FF']);

  new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    computed: {
      color: function() {
        return colorScale(0.5);
      }
     }
  });

  colorScale.range(['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000']);
</script>
```

In this example I want to see a pale red circle. Is there a way to make this happen? Maybe there is a way to refresh the computed variable or to keep the scale in the Vue instance data object.

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/tyrone-tudehope/composing-d3-visualizations-with-vue-js-c65084ccb686 and some other examples for how to use D3 with Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert an additional data variable and change it externally:

```js
const v = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data() {
    return {
      colorScale: d3.scaleLinear().range(['#FFFFFF', '#0000FF'])
    }
  },
  computed: {
    color: function() {
      return this.colorScale(0.5);
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().range(['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000'])
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" :fill="color"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. The downside is that I have to reset the scale variable, it would be nicer if I could work with the same one and just change range, domain or something else.